How mapping onChange value react-select v5
How to fix this error without any when I try to map a value with onChange in react-hook-form?
Errors:
Array:

An argument of type "T[]" cannot be assigned to a parameter of type "OnChangeValue<T, is Multi>".ts(2345)

Single:

An argument of type "T | undefined" cannot be assigned to a parameter of type "OnChangeValue<T, isMulti> | undefined".
The type "T" cannot be assigned to the type "OnChangeValue<T, isMulti> | undefined".ts(2345)

Code:
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import Select, { MultiValue, OnChangeValue, SingleValue } from "react-select";

import { VirtualOption } from "./types";

type PValue<T> = T | T[];

interface VirtualSelectAdapterProps<T, isMulti extends boolean = false>
  extends Omit<VirtualSelectProps<T, isMulti>, "value" | "onChange"> {
  value?: isMulti extends true ? T[] : T;
  onChange: (value?: OnChangeValue<T, isMulti>) => void;
}

function isMultiValue<T>(
  arg: MultiValue<T> | SingleValue<T>,
): arg is MultiValue<T> {
  return Array.isArray(arg);
}

export const VirtualSelectAdapter = <T, isMulti extends boolean = false>(
  props: VirtualSelectAdapterProps<T, isMulti>,
) => {
  const { isMulti } = props;

  const onChange = useCallback(
    (value?: OnChangeValue<VirtualOption<T>, isMulti>) => {
      if (isMultiValue(value)) {
        const values = value.map((item) => item.value);

        return props.onChange(values);
      } else {
        props.onChange(value?.value);
      }
    },
    [props, isMulti],
  );

  return <VirtualCustomSelect<T, isMulti> {...props} onChange={onChange} />;
};

interface VirtualSelectProps<T, isMulti extends boolean = false> {
  options: VirtualOption<T>[];
  placeholder?: string;
  drawCount?: number;
  isMulti: isMulti;
  onChange: (value?: OnChangeValue<VirtualOption<T>, isMulti>) => void;
  value?: PValue<T>;
}

export const VirtualCustomSelect = <T, isMulti extends boolean>({
  options = [],
  drawCount = 200,
  placeholder,
  isMulti,
  onChange,
}: VirtualSelectProps<T, isMulti>) => {
  const filter = (searchValue: string) => {
    const data = [];
    for (const iterator of options) {
      if (data.length > drawCount) break;
      if (currentValueIncludesSearchValue(searchValue, iterator.label))
        data.push(iterator);
    }
    return data;
  };

  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(filter(""));
  return (
    <Select<VirtualOption<T>, isMulti>
      isMulti={isMulti}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={(newValue) => onChange(newValue)}
      onInputChange={(newValue) => setFiltered(filter(newValue))}
      options={filtered}
    />
  );
};

const currentValueIncludesSearchValue = (
  searchValue: string,
  currentValue: string,
) => {
  return currentValue.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
};

I tried different generics and condition (e.g if(isMulti)) and errors is very similar
